# Поиск всех однострочных комментариев. Регулярное выражение

Tags: javascript, reactjs, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть регулярное выражение:

```
\/\/(?!.*(?:https?:\/\/))(?![^"'\n]*https?:\/\/)[^\n]*$
```

Его я вставляю в поиск VSCode для нахождения всех однострочных комментариев.

Но у меня также затрагивается, ссылки, в самом коде. В основном именно выделяются после //. Также затрагивает регулярные выражения в уодее. Язык JS.

В чем ошибка может быть? Мне нужно чтобы только сами однострочные комментарии выделял и всё.